# Facebook CPM enum adgroup creation issues

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I posted this as a bug on FB as well... Still, I'm asking here to see if I missed something.

Basically, I'm able to create an adgroup using `bid_type=CPC` (as requested by October 2 breaking changes) and with `bid_info={'clicks':121}`. However, when I try using analog call to create a CPM adgroup, I'm getting an error. Here's the full call:
`curl  -F "campaign_id=SOME_EXISTING_CAMPAIGN_ID" -F "bid_type=CPM" -F "bid_info={'reach':122}" -F "name=test 8-221048" -F "adgroup_status=1" -F "targeting={'countries':['US']}" -F "creative={'title':'test 8-221048','body':'test 8-221048','image_hash':'SOME_IMAGE_HASH','link_url':'http://www.somesite.com/','type':1}" -F "redownload=1"  "https://graph.facebook.com/act_ACCOUNT_ID/adgroups?access_token=VALID_TOKEN"`

Response I get is: 
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => Exception
            [message] => Invalid bid info for this ad. Please verify that your bid specifies appropriate objectives for the bid type and that all bids are properly formatted currency amounts.
            [code] => 1487370
        )

)

Anyone else having same issues?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are bidding reach you'd have to use absolute_cpm instead of just cpm. The legacy cpm bid type is only for bidding on impressions.

Comment: Yes, thank you - I got an answe from FB. There was an error in their documentation where they listed 'REACH' as option for CPM :)